# How to unlock new Mounts?

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

I already did the **Master of horses** quest, so I've the option to change my mount on Haven when I go to Dennet location, but all of them are blocked. **How do I get new mounts**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According the IGN:

> Mounts are rideable creatures in Dragon Age: Inquisition that can
>   either be found, purchased, or rewarded by completing certain quests.
>   There are plenty of mounts, including exotic mounts, that can be found
>   in different places of the world. Other mounts can be purchased once
>   you have convinced Horsemaster Dennet to join the Inquisition, with
>   more mounts available to buy over time.

For a list of how to acquire different mounts, you can have a look [here](http://au.ign.com/wikis/dragon-age-inquisition/Mounts) and [here](http://dragonage.wikia.com/wiki/Mounts)